# Tableau constant reference line issue when changing date range

Tags: tableau-api

I have a few reference lines showing the previous year's averages.  The problem I'm running into is when I select a smaller date range (like 10 days vs 90 days) the chart just cuts to that date range instead of resizing the entire chart so that you can look closer at the selected days.  Is there a way around this?
[image]

This is not how I'd like it to look when I isolate down to a smaller timeframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved...changed the date to discrete that fixed the issue.